# window.location then window.alert (immediately close) ( to avoid alert at white screen)

Tags: javascript

@edit

I want to redirect from page1 to page2 and  popup alert/message on page2, but now alert is shows up on page1  instead of page2.

Comment: The way your question is structured, it is hard to read.

Comment: If you are doing alert on the page as it is loading, it will stop what it is doing. So if it is white, than you are stopping the rendering from firing. So you need to wait to show it when the page has loaded.

Comment: window.alert doesn't trigger navigation on its own. It's possible that what's going on is that your captcha form is submitting, and sending users to a different page -- but it's not clear from your description where or how the alert is being fired.  Can you include the relevant code in your question?

Comment: I just want to see alert at my page with login form instead of white page, how to make it

Comment: @DanielBeck yes, i have function with switch and :  case 'CHECK_CAPTCHA':
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location.href = '/login.php?errors=checkcaptcha';
    alert('Check your captcha.');</script>";
          break;   But now alert is dissapearing in 1ms, cant almost see it

Comment: reverse the order? put the alert on the next page?

Comment: @epascarello then i got alert on white page and when i click OK, its redirect again to my login form page. I want alert on my login form page

Comment: Don't use alert! That's old school web. Try flash messages. In your case it will be easier to implement.

Comment: @Zak I just want one alert/ popup message whatever

Comment: flash? It is not early 2000s

Comment: Easy, remove the alert. In your login.php check if you have the parameter errors=checkcaptcha.  If true, render some html code to display Check your captcha on your login page.

Comment: If you do not want the flash white, than you need to have the alert show up on the next page. So you would need to use a cookie or querystring value and check for it on page load and than show your message.

Comment: @epascarello, not flash (technology), flash messages in php. Ephemeral messages.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to accomplish this would be to use a [modal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal). It's more elegant than window.alert and should work well for your use case.

Comment: Can you expand on why a modal is more elegant? Congrats on your first answer!

Comment: yes but it isnt supported with firefox